# Mule CE query params

Tags: http, request, mule, parameters

i use Mule 3.6.1 CE and i make a Rest request passing some query params. My request is in https. The query on rest client is correct and when i pass parameter limit=3 the called service return 3 results. When i make the same request by Mule the service return all results. It seems that param is not passed in query url. Header params is passed because service authorize my call.

```
 <http:request config-ref="HTTPS_Request_Configuration"  path="/concept_tree" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" > 
        <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="limit" value="3"/>
                <http:header headerName="X-Ape-Auth-Client-Id" value="xxxxxx"/>
             </http:request-builder>

         </http:request>
```

Some of you had this problem?

Comment: You need to add additional details, send your request trough a proxy or use wireshark  to inspect the raw http request to make sure your parameter is there.

Comment: request pass through a proxy. I tried to use the old connector http:outbound with address paramenter ".../concept_tre?limit=3" and web service return 3 results. I don't want to use the old connector because in mule  3.6.1 is deprecated. In both cases i print in console the full message and in the message with http:request thera are less information about http..... fields.